# Show hidden rect with text on hover of another poly

Tags: css, svg, hover

I need to use pure svg for a project. I know how to get this effect simply with divs but I dont know how to make it work with svg, I dont know what im doing wrong.

I want to show a hidden black rect with white text when you hover on another polygon (and the polygon is 0.1 of opacity normal and changes to 0.8 of opacity on the same hover) Something like a tooltip with opacity and with a nice smooth transition, but pure SVG.

```css
.showme {
    opacity: 0.3;
}

.showme:hover {
    opacity: 0.8;    
}

.desc {
    visibility: hidden;
}

.showme:hover + .desc {
   visibility: visible;
}
```

```html
<svg width="200" height="200" viewBox="0 0 1000 300"
     xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" >
    <rect x="1" y="1" width="998" height="298" fill="blue" class="showme"/>    
</svg>

<svg width="200" height="200" viewBox="0 0 1000 300"
     xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" class="desc" >
  <rect x="1" y="1" width="998" height="298" fill="black" />     
 <text x="250" y="150" font-family="Verdana" font-size="55" fill="white">Hello world!</text>
</svg>
```

Please help :/

Thanks.

Comment: see http://www.petercollingridge.co.uk/data-visualisation/mouseover-effects-svgs, seems you cannot change other svg style, but you can through onmouseover.

Comment: What do you mean by "pure SVG"? You have two separate SVGs here in an HTML.  So it's not pure in this situation.  Why are you using two SVGs? Is that a requirement of your solution?  Also, CSS is CSS, if you could get it working for DIVs, it should also work for SVGs.  But I don't see a way to do this with DIVs either.

Comment: Yes I need to do it with svg, not divs, but rects with text behave funny with hover effects. This is what I want to do but with svg http://jsfiddle.net/D3N1553/7extjqy8/ [link]

Answer (score 1):

Keeping your svg, you can do with like this, but you'll need some slight changes:

```
<svg  width="200" height="200" viewBox="0 0 1000 300"
     xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" >
    <rect onmouseover='document.getElementById("desc").style.visibility = "visible"' onmouseout='document.getElementById("desc").style.visibility = "hidden"' x="1" y="1" width="998" height="298" fill="blue" class="showme"/>    
</svg>

<svg width="200" height="200" viewBox="0 0 1000 300"
     xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" id="desc" >
  <rect x="1" y="1" width="998" height="298" fill="black" />     
 <text x="250" y="150" font-family="Verdana" font-size="55" fill="white">Hello world!</text>
</svg>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/q6kkhvz7/2/